# Any Google API in perl working with OAuth

Tags: perl, api

I've looked at Net::Google, and 90% of the modules use AuthSub with a mandatory login/password. The right way for a web application to interact with Google applications on behalf of a customer is to use OAuth. That way, the authentication is done by Google, and the application does not know the user's password. This is supported by Net::Google::DocumentsList for example.

Are you aware of modules that can work well with Picasa and Blogger, for example, using OAuth. The current Net::Google::PicasaWeb handles read-only queries, no add/remove/update actions.

Comment: I've implemented a sample imap client using oauth in Perl : https://github.com/fser/google-imap-oauth
Basically, I transposed google's Python code sample into Perl, but it works quiet well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this blog entry with an example, http://blog.case.edu/jeremy.smith/2009/03/30/using_2legged_oauth_with_google_apps_in_perl, perhaps it will get you started.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up writing my own library, it was not very hard